# Expo stuck on loading screen

Tags: react-native, expo

i was having an issue and tried to downgrade to yarn 1 to fix it, and it didnt work, so i went back to yarn 3. from that point forward, i have not been able to start my expo app locally, even with a fresh checkout. there must be some cache somewhere that is causing this problem, but i have tried clearing everything many times, removed yarn and reinstalled, started computer, removed the repo, etc

the error i see in my js debugger is:

```
TypeError: EventTarget.apply is not a function (it is undefined), js engine: hermes
Invariant Violation: Failed to call into JavaScript module method AppRegistry.runApplication(). Module has not been registered as callable. Bridgeless Mode: false. Registered callable JavaScript modules (n = 9): Systrace, JSTimers, HeapCapture, SamplingProfiler, RCTLog, RCTDeviceEventEmitter, RCTNativeAppEventEmitter, GlobalPerformanceLogger, HMRClient.
        A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect. This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native., js engine: hermes
```

ive upgraded to latest version of expo (49.0.21) and this is my metro config

```
const { createMetroConfiguration } = require("expo-yarn-workspaces");

const config = createMetroConfiguration(__dirname);

const { transformer, resolver } = config;

config.transformer = {
  ...transformer,
  babelTransformerPath: require.resolve("react-native-svg-transformer"),
};

config.resolver = {
  ...resolver,
  assetExts: resolver.assetExts.filter((ext) => ext !== "svg"),
  sourceExts: [...resolver.sourceExts, "svg"],
};

config.resolver.blockList = [config.resolver?.blockList ?? [], /\/\.build\/.*/].flat();

config.resetCache = true;

module.exports = config;
```

any tips? have spent hours on this and would love any advice!